# Partially orthogonal error term in Regression

Tags: regression, conditional-expectation, orthogonal

Suppose I have a model:

$Y = X_1 \beta_{1} + X_2\beta_2 + C$, where $C$ is independent to $X_1$ but not $X_2$. If we naively perform linear regression, say by concatenating $X= (X_1 X_2)$ and considering $\hat{\beta} = (X^TX)^{-1} X^T Y$ and looked at the components, we would see that $\hat{\beta}_1$ is unbiased for $\beta_1$ but $\hat{\beta}_2$ is biased for $\beta_2$.

This makes a lot of sense to me, especially the latter fact, but I am having trouble proving the first fact. I have tried looking at the bias (which is related to $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T \mathbb{E}(C | X)$, but still no juice. Can anyone give me a nudge in the right direction? Is there something really trivial I am not seeing?